# Hadoop namenode web UI not opening in CDH4

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, cloudera

I recently installed the CDH distribution of Cloudera to create a 2 node cluster. From the Cloudera Manager UI, all services are running fine.

All the command line tools (hive etc ) are also working fine and I am able to read and write data to hdfs.

However the namenode (and datanode) web UI alone is not opening. Checking on netstat -a | grep LISTEN, the processes are listening on the assigned ports and there are no firewall rules which are blocking the connections ( I already disabled iptables)

I initially though that it could be a DNS issue but even the IP address is not working. The Cloudera Manager installed on the same machine on another port is opening fine.

Any pointers on how to debug this problem?

Comment: Are you pointing your web browser to the correct addresss?

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue.

First it was because NAMENODE in safemode
then after because of two IP address (I have two NIC configured on CDH Cluster one internal connectivity of the servers (10.0.0.1) and other is to connect servers form Internet (192.168.0.1))

When i try to open NAMENODE GUI form any of the server connected to cluster on network 10.0.0.1 then GUI is opening and works fine but from other any other machine connected to servers by 192.168.0.1 network it fails.